# Export MS Access Report to PDF based on condition

Tags: ms-access, pdf, export, report, criteria

Is there any way to export a report in MS Access to PDF based on a certain criteria/field on the report?

I have created a productivity report in MS Access. Instead of exporting 50 pages into 1 PDF, is there a way to export based on the manager's name? The field for the managers name is included on the actual report.

Comment: Is the report only loading 1 manager per run? The event handlers for a report can be tricky so I'm not sure about using the actual report. If there was a step we could take to narrow down the manager's name beforehand I think that would be easiest. (Query, perhaps?)

Comment: @overmind i do have all the data that is on the form, in one table (the managers names included).

Comment: Is the report for 1 manager? Or all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take this idea and play with it.  Insert this into a Module

```
Option Explicit

Dim g_ManagerReportFilterEnabled As Boolean
Dim g_ManagerReportFilter As String

Public Function IsManagerReportFilterEnabled() As Boolean
    IsManagerReportFilterEnabled = g_ManagerReportFilterEnabled
End Function

Public Function GetManagerReportFilter() As String
    GetManagerReportFilter = g_ManagerReportFilter
End Function

Public Sub ExportFilteredManagerReportToPDF(strManagerName As String)
On Error GoTo ExportFilteredManagerReportToPDF_ErrorHandler

    g_ManagerReportFilterEnabled = True
    g_ManagerReportFilter = "[MyManagerNameField] = " & Chr(34) & strManagerName & Chr(34)
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "MyReportName", acFormatPDF, "MyPath:\MyFileName.PDF", False

    GoTo ExitMe

ExportFilteredManagerReportToPDF_ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print err.Number & ": " & err.Description
ExitMe:
    g_ManagerReportFilterEnabled = False
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

and review the variables you need to replace.  And this into Report_Open of your report:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    If IsManagerReportFilterEnabled = True Then
        Me.Filter = GetManagerReportFilter
        Me.FilterOn = True
    End If

End Sub
```

So the issue this code is trying to solve is that we want to use DoCmd.OutputTo to output our PDF, but it does not take a Filter parameter.  So we work around this by setting up two global variables (I know...) which let us know if we should use the Manager filter and what that filter is.  When we run ExportFilteredManagerReportToPDF and pass through a name, the sub will output the report to PDF.  Because of the code attached the report, when OutputTo runs, the report will detect whether the filter is enabled, and if it is, apply it.  Then OutputTo finishes its work and the PDF is output.

To run this for manager John Smith, say, you can run this from the debug window:

```
 ExportFilteredManagerReportToPDF "John Smith"
```