# Saving a specific record in a report to .pdf

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need assistance in creating a pdf file for a certain record in a report.  Currently it's saving all the records.  What do I need to do to save only the current record that I'm viewing?

```
{DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Eagle-MasterERP"}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export MS Access Report to PDF based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453238/export-ms-access-report-to-pdf-based-on-condition)

Comment: Alternatively: edit the report's query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302369/how-to-output-access-report-with-condition